# iPhone not connected. Xcode will continue when iPhone is connected

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I have my iPhone connected to Xcode. It used to work just fine recently. I see it in the Devices and Simulators section, but when I try to compile my app, it says:

> D's iPhone 6S is not connected. Xcode will continue when D's iPhone 6S is connected.

In the Devices and Simulators I see it as disconnected.

I tried restarting the phone, turning it's wifi on and off. It's connected to the same wifi network, I tried restarting Xcode, nothing. I run Xcode 9, Beta 6 at the moment. Does anyone has similar issue and hopefully know how to solve it?

Comment: Have you tried to connect it with USB or only via WiFi?

Comment: If you have upgraded your phone to a former beta, you should try via USB. Beta9 erased all my music, so there are side effects.

Comment: Hmm, I've upgraded to beta 9, but I didn't notice anything unusual happening in my phone. There was an issue with the usb, but now its working wirelessly. I don't get it really...

Comment: Maybe, just connecting it with USB restored some security token that was lost with the upgrade.

Comment: I had the same problem, but got it working af several attempts. I toggled the `Connect via network` button and restarting Xcode and rebooted the phone.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Apparently, more people have this issue. The only "solution" I found was to connect the iphone with a USB, run the app and then try to run it using wifi. This usually solves my problem.

Answer (score 108):

**Troubleshooting:**

1. plug in your iPhone.
2. Open Xcode
3. go to `window` -> `Devices and Simulators`
4. Right click on your device
5. click `Unpair Device` and unplug it.
6. restart Xcode
7. restart your iPhone.
8. Connect your iPhone via USB
9. run your app
10. then unplug it, and it should run via the wifi again.

**Set up**

1. **Window -> Devices and Simulators**

[image]

2. Choose your device from the list.

[image]

3. Tick the box for "connect via network."

[image]

Comment: l Trial and error led me to this answer.  I tried all the other answers here at the time.

Comment: I was borrowing cables from my coworkers, then enabled wireless build, now you let me unpair the device, oh man, I'm not going to ask for a cable one more time.

Comment: I just had to unpair and reconnect my phone -- didn't even have to restart anything.

Comment: @DustinB, that's great!

Comment: I unpaired my devices and now it doesn't find them again using USB ... wtf... neither my iPhone nor my iPad ... Maybe it's time to reboot the MacBook

Comment: @randomcontrol, what os and Xcode version are you using?

Comment: @Honey, in step 9, it says “then unplug it.”

Comment: @Honey, ah...indeed, Thank you.  I think I assumed a step.  I updated it.

Comment: @Honey, up to you.  It was a good comment.  You know what they say about assumptions ;). Your comment made my answer better.

Comment: I found that just by going to Windows->Devices and simulator that Xcode was able to reconnect.

Comment: There are times for me when that wasn’t enough.  .

Answer (score 61):

In Window > Devices and Simulators, right click on your iPhone and "Connect with IP address", then enter the iPhone IP address and you're connected.

Comment: Running USB and disconnecting doesn't work for me. This looks like the way to do it then.

Comment: Xcode Version 9.1 - no option to "Connect with IP address" - only method I could find is USB cable.

Comment: Xcode 9.1 - reconnecting via WIFI, I have to open "Devices and Simulators" window and then Xcode will continue connecting when your device is unlocked!

Comment: Connect via IP address does not work for me. The only way to restore the connection is to plug USB cable, and click the checkbox "connect via network" again whenever it appears.

Comment: This is the correct answer for when you don't actually have a lightning data cable!

Comment: Finally working solution

Answer (score 48):

**Turn off WIFI** on **Mac**, and also on your **iPhone** too. Then **turn on WIFI** again on both devices.

I frequently face this issue since I don't use USB cable to build the app to my iPhone. So this is my usual way to resolve the connection problem.

Comment: I've had some luck doing this but does not work for me most of the time.

Comment: Quickly turning off and back on macOS wifi via the menu bar has worked every time for me, and the problem occurs less frequently.

Comment: Works for me either. No need to turn something off. It'll even continue deploying to your device after it finds it on the network.

Comment: I've Unpaired and restarted Xcode and the phone but no result. Disabling and enabling Wifi fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: Works for me. Thanks !

Answer (score 27):

As **Sam H.**'s answer, can `Connect via IP Address`.  This is `XCode 9 or 9.1` 's function.  And need your device update to `iOS11 +`

[image]

Answer (score 10):

You can also connect via IP address

While Xcode is open, go to

Windows -> Device and Simulators

right click your device and connect via IP address. You can get your phone IP address from settings under wifi and clicking the info button on the network.

Answer (score 9):

Restarting the wifi on my Mac worked for me.

Comment: This worked for me also, turning WiFi off on both the Mac and iPhone and then back on worked first time.  The simplest things are usually overlooked. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

I was able to reconnect using this method:

1. Disconnect/Unplugged the device from Mac
2. Close X-Code
3. Run "sudo pkill usbmuxd" in terminal
4. Reopen Xcode
5. Reconnect Device

Try this if unpairing method does not work.

Comment: Thanks it works. Can you explain the process ? What is usbmuxd ?

Comment: @ReaperSoon it is a socket that operates the connections from and to iOS devices

Answer (score 6):

I'm using Xcode 9.1 and suddenly had this issue.After reading other answers a realized it is a Xcode bug via wifi debug.My solution was to connect the iphone with a USB, then go to the Add Additional Simulators,then come to the interface below,uncheck "connect via network".
Problem sovled,and back to debug via a USB.

[image]

Comment: If this option does not appear, try to reattach your device.

Answer (score 4):

Making Cellular data Off solved my problem

Comment: In my scenario I haven't used the cellular even :(

Comment: I also had to turn off Cellular data, but once the connection was successful with Xcode, I was able to turn back on Cellular data, and the wireless connection to Xcode still worked.

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue when I changed my network connection on my Mac and in this case reconnecting the phone with an USB cable doesn't work. I had to restart xCode.

Answer (score 3):

I had to update Xcode in my case. I tried literally everything else in this thread.

Comment: Yeah, they should consider displaying an "Update Xcode" message instead of "Device not connected" in the pop-up that appears when the app fails to run. I found out the issue after viewing the logs in `Window` -> `Devices and Simulators`

Answer (score 2):

I had to  reopen Xcode with my iPhone X unlocked and then I had to open Windows->Devices immediately afterwards.

Then the message was changed into:"iPhone X is busy: Preparing debugger support for iPhone X"

Answer (score 2):

Also make sure your iOS device is on the same wifi network as your Mac, otherwise Xcode will insist you connect your device via USB, even if you've checked the box to use wireless development for that device.

Answer (score 2):

There could be more than one reason why xcode forgets the device often. One of them could be the dynamic IP which is assigned automatically.

Apart from general troubleshooting (device is unlocked etc), here are few suggestions based on my experience.

1) Check if you are using the **SAME WIFI** on computer and device.

2) In Xcode > Devices and Simulators > Right Click > **Unpair Device** and connect again.

3) Prefer to use **static IP**. At least for the device (Give Manual IP address in the iPhone).

4) In Xcode > Devices and Simulators > **Connect via IP Address**

5) **Use USB cable** to run the app and then unplug to use wireless solves it most often.

6) Disconnect and Reconnect Wireless on Computer & Mobile Device

7) Turn off the **Cellular** Data

8) Turn off any **VPN** you are using.

9) Check your Network Settings on Computer and Device. Disable any suspecious setting (**Proxy** etc).

10) **Restart** Device and Computer. It often resolves few network interface problems.

Answer (score 2):

In my case a **pending software update on my iPhone** was preventing it from accepting new builds from Xcode - even over USB.

I tried all the other suggestions in this thread and nothing worked, but **accepting the pending update on my phone fixed the problem**.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the Apple engineers don't really have networking under control.

Typically, a dance of (in the order of increasing inconvenience)

- Toggling "Connect via Network"
- Toggling "WiFi" on Mac and iPhone
- Unpairing + Repairing the device in the Xcode organizer
- Restarting (yes, just like Windows) the Mac and the iPhone

works for me.

Answer (score 2):

I also keep running into this problem with Xcode 15 running on M1 MacBook Air and iPhone 11 running iOS 17.

One or all of these steps always solves it for me:-

1. If you have a VPN, try turning it off once and see if it connects. I use Nord VPN and its threat protection seemed to have prevented Xcode from connecting to the iPhone. If that wasn't the issue, keep reading.
2. Use a Mac App named [DevCleaner for Xcode](https://apps.apple.com/in/app/devcleaner-for-xcode/id1388020431?mt=12). This app is actually for cleaning up space after app development. But for some reason that I'm not too sure about, cleaning all the components shown in this app often solves the above problem.
3. Then, in Xcode, Go to Product -> Clean Build Folder... then restart Xcode.
4. In the iPhone, go to Settings -> Privacy and Security -> Developer Mode. Turn it off then on again. The phone will restart and ask permissions to switch developer mode ON and Trust the MacBook again.
5. At this point if you see the device list in Xcode, you will see that Xcode is preparing the phone for development (copying files between the Mac and iPhone, etc.)

And that's it. You should be able to get back to work on your apps. Let me know in the comments if this isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

This is just to add the other possible reasons that the answers forgot to mention:

You got a new phone and Xcode is trying to connect to the old phone:
    Window<< Devices and Simulators: 
          Press the + button and connect your phone via usb cable and click
          your on your device. It should add it at that point.

You could also try running bluetooth instead of wifi, but it might still do the same problems. *Make sure your device is connected correctly*

Answer (score 1):

1. Restart Xcode & if issue persists do steps 2-4.
2. Open Devices and Simulators window in Xcode (shortcut is `⌘⇧2` command+shift+2)
3. Make sure your device is active (press home button & enter passcode if needed)
4. Open terminal & run `netstat` command.

You device will be reconnected

Answer (score 1):

I had to reset the trusted computers from phone settings -> Developer -> "Clear Trusted Computers". Then it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue with Xcode 15.0.1 and iPhone 15 Pro Max (iOS 17). I had to disconnect my Cisco AnyConnect VPN then it showed up right away.

Should have figured, AnyConnect messes with a lot of apple features like Continuity and using your iPad as a second screen. It has to do with the ip addresses it uses from what I found last time, they conflict with Apples private network.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone did what I did: I used to have wireless connection with my mac mini but one day I decided to use a cable. From that day I had problems with my devices, I always had to use usb the first time I opened Xcode. When I removed cable connection everything worked fine as before.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a combination of the above solutions and can't pinpoint what solved it.

When Xcode was stuck on trying to connect to my wireless iPad, I had to do was start browsing with Safari on my iPad. I think that somehow refreshes the network on the iPad.

The Xcode's 'Device and simulator' may not properly reflect the connection status between the device and mac so **after** browsing with your iPad/iPhone **hit run on Xcode and then just wait till they find each other**

Answer (score 0):

For me it was because of switching to a new device, which led to existence of two devices having the same name. It took some time to notice that I was attempting to run the app on the previously retired device. Solution was to select the correct device as a run destination and unpair the old one.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is that your device’s Developer Mode is turned off. It's the default.

The warning will looks like this on the setting:

[image: Phone setting developer mode warning on Xcode device setting]

Answer (score 0):

Just Disabling "Multipath Networking"

Settings>Developer

[enter link description here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/737907)

Answer (score 0):

**xCode problem to connect iPhone**

- if you use some VPN client - try to disable it